# Howto handle nested transaction with ActiveRecord 3.0.4 and db_cleaner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

We are using db_cleaner with clean method `:transaction` on a Rails 3.0.4 app (that we can't upgrade at the moment) with a MySQL 5.x DB. We can not use `:truncation`, cause we'd loose seed data.

Now we face the following problem. ActiveRecord automatically generates a transaction when for example `:create` or `:destroy` are called on an ActiveRecord based object. In our RSpec suite we're using Machinist factories to create our test data for every test. Now in case we're testing functionality that creates it's own transaction, we face the problem, that the begin-commit cycle of our `Factory.make!` call inside a test not only quits the inner transaction (opened by `:create`) but also quits the transaction that was opened inside the tested code. In result the rollback triggered by db_cleaner can not roll back anything, and we still have our test data inside our database after a test ran.

I think somebody must have faced this problem already. As MySQL does not support nested transactions, but ActiveRecord does simulate them by creating savepoints since version 2.3.2, we did not expect that behavior.

Can anyone provide info, how to solve that particular problem?